# How to Pass An Array of Custom Types to PostgreSQL Function in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, npgsql

I have the following type definition and function that consumes it:

```
create type my_type as
(
    id bigint,
    value character varying(100)
);


create or replace function my_function (
    my_array my_type[])
    returns table (id bigint)
    language 'plpgsql'
as $BODY$
begin
return query
    select id from my_table as t
    where t.id in (
        select ar.id
        from unnest(my_array) as ar
    );
end;
$BODY$;
```

The function above might be nonsensical functionally, but its simplified for minimum working example sake. I could call `my_function` in PostgreSQL this way:

```
select * from my_function(array[(1, 't')::my_type, (3, 'b')::my_type]);
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/SQAn2KZ4

I'm using **.Net Core 8.0** and **Npgsql 8.0.2** for the test code. Given the following POCO:

```
public class MyType
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

I have tried to call `my_function` this way:

```
var dsBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder("my-connection-string");
dsBuilder.MapComposite<MyType>("my_type");
using var ds = dsBuilder.Build();
using var conn = ds.OpenConnection();

var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from my_function(@arr)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
     "arr",
     new MyType[] {
         new MyType(){ Id = 1, Value = "t" },
         new MyType(){ Id = 3, Value = "b" },
     }
)
```

The code above doesn't work, it gave an error saying `Writing values of 'Program+MyType[]' is not supported for parameters having no NpgsqlDbType or DataTypeName`. I also have tried to pass the parameter as `IEnumerable` and `List` to no avail. I do wonder how should I call `my_function` from C# using `NpgsqlDataSource`?

[The documentations](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html?tabs=datasource) only shows example for a singular object. I have tried to look around for a way to pass an array of user  type and only found example in python using tuples.

I have the final option to just push every `MyType` instance each in their own function calls, but that will be terribly inefficient and require significant changes to the PostgreSQL function. Alternatively, I could change the parameter to accept json - but is it the only way?

Comment: Try removing the 2nd MapComposite line: `my_type[]` is not a composite type - it's an array. You also don't need to cast @arr with `::test_type[]` - Npgsql infers the type automatically. Finally, there seems to be some type confusion: you define a MyType .NET type, but then use TestType below.

Comment: @ShayRojansky yeah, some of it was typo. I tried without the second mapping previously and still not working, forgot to remove it from the question. guess i'm too tired with fumbling around on this all day.